# What does "to feel as a nutmeg must do when it's grated" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, metaphors

> ‘Ah, Master Cromwell!’ More rubs his hands together. ‘I relish you, I
>   do indeed. Now I **feel as a nutmeg must do when it's grated**. A lesser
>   man – a lesser lawyer – would say, “I have read Tyndale's work, and I
>   find no fault there.” But Cromwell won't be tripped – he casts it
>   back, he asks me, rather, have you read Tyndale? And I admit it. I
>   have studied the man. I have picked apart his so-called translations,
>   and I have done it letter by letter. I read him, of course, I do. By
>   licence. From my bishop.’
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mante

What is the meaning of "**to feel as a nutmeg must do when it's grated**"? Irritated?

Comment: More suggests that Cromwell has pressed him hard against almost invisibly small sharp points to subtly abrasive effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When nutmeg is grated, it is broken up into little bits by the violent action of something much more powerful than itself. This results in something a little different from the original nutmeg, and arguably more useful, but not the same whole piece.

That's the metaphor being used here: More is expressing how forceful Cromwell is, and (presumably) how potentially transformative, as though he were a kitchen utensil and his opponents merely spices to be made ready for cooking.

<sub>("Must do", by the way, means the same as "must feel" in this context; it's referring back to the previous verb. This is a rather archaic construction, used for effect.)</sub>

Comment: +1 But the use of *do* here is still current in BrE, though my impression is that it's dying out there, too.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yeah, I figured I'd hedge with "rather". On this side of the pond, there's no question: it's archaic. Elsewhere it's not quite so old-fashioned.